# Trying to edit array values by reference in foreach loop

Tags: php, arrays, drupal, foreach

I've got this code:

```
    foreach ($variables['results'] as $group => &$results) {

        if (isset($headers[$group])) {

            $results[0]0] = "<a href='".$results[0][0]. "' />". "Title" . "</a>";

            //drupal_set_message(print_r($results[0][0], true));


            $string .= theme('table', array('header' => array_values($headers[$group]), 'rows' => $results));
        }
    }
```

I am trying to modify the $results[0][0] to be a link instead.

My IDE is saying that I'm doing something incorrectly - what is it? What is the correct/preferred way to do this (specifically with Drupal, if possible, PHP best practices otherwise)

Comment: `$results[0]0]` - missing `[` perhaps?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
$results[0]0]
```

to:

```
$results[0][0]
```

Comment: Wow, I didn't even see that.